# Deploy simple standalone spring mvc application in docker container

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, docker

I have to deploy simple standalone spring mvc application in docker container. [I started with this application](https://www.journaldev.com/14476/spring-mvc-example) and haven't been able to find a solution to deploy it within docker.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.20-jre8
COPY spring-mvc-example.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

I am getting the following error when I execute

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 springmvc
```

ERROR

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-example]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@77c87bba]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4970)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@27179421]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:699)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:88)
    ... 17 more

30-Mar-2018 18:33:40.268 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/spring-mvc-example.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-example]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Where did your WAR come from? It looks like it is corrupt. `invalid CEN header (bad signature)`

Comment: I have downloaded it from the link i have given.

Comment: Should i try with some different war ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution , seems like it was because of the some corrupted files in my local repository.

I deleted all the files in local maven repository and downloaded them again. and followed the same steps as above then was able to deploy the war successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the example project working. Here are the steps I took to package it.

Download the zip file of the project [from here](https://www.journaldev.com/?wpdmact=process&did=MjI2LmhvdGxpbms=). Unzip and build the project.

```
cd /path/to/spring-mvc-example
mvn package
```

Copy the `spring-mvc-example.war` from the `/path/to/spring-mvc-example/targets/spring-mvc-example.war` file into the folder with your Dockerfile

My Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.20-jre8
COPY spring-mvc-example.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Build your docker file

```
docker build -t so-49579717 .
```

Run your container.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 so-49579717
```

I don't see any of the errors you did above. As you didn't mention the maven package step, maybe you were trying to package the zip file into the container?

Comment: No i have done the mvn packaging in the same way. I tried the same steps again as you mentioned. I am still getting the same error. Don't know what is the reason .